# How does the director in the Builder class Sets a null int to 0?

Tags: java, design-patterns, null, int, builder

I'm studying a simple example of Builder Design Pattern.
So my question is, if I try to instantiate my Phone class directly, it wont accept null for the int parameter which is understandable since it is a primitive type.
 However when I use the builder and I don't set the value of an Int variable(which will remain null) the director somehow changes its value to 0.
`Phone p=new PhoneBuilder().setOs("Android").setRam(2).getPhone();`
 
`p.Processor == null` at this point. so in `getPhone()` when the phone constructor is called, the value of `processor` is supposed to be `null` I tried to watch the variable with the debugger but I can't find nor understand why it changes from `null` to `0`.

```
public class Phone {    

    private String os;  
    private int ram; 
    private String processor;   
    private double screenSize;   
    private int battery;    

    public Phone(String os, int ram, String processor, double screenSize, int battery) {
        super();
        this.os = os;
        this.ram = ram;
        this.processor = processor;
        this.screenSize = screenSize;
        this.battery = battery;
    }

}
```

and here is my builder:

```
    public class PhoneBuilder {

        private String os; 
        private int ram; 
        private String processor;
        private double screenSize;
        private int battery; 

        public PhoneBuilder setOs(String os) {
            this.os = os;
            return this;
        }

        public PhoneBuilder setRam(int ram) {
            this.ram = ram;
            return this;
        //...

        public Phone getPhone() {
            return new Phone(os, ram, processor, screenSize, battery);
        }
    }
```

Comment: when you do net set instance variable explicitly, it defaults to 0 for `int` and `null` for `String` (but `Integer` will be `null` since its an object)

Comment: So how is the builder setting them implicitly?

Comment: The builder isn't, it's a behaviour of Java.  A primitive can't have a null, null is only possible for objects, so primitives have implicit initial values if they are not explicitly declared.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: This is what I don't understand. Why does Java behave when the constructor of phone is called in the Builder and doesn't when I try to instantiate the phone class with a null parameter in the Main?

Comment: ah I got it @Taylor .. thanx since I'm writing myself in the constructor Null it doesnt compile, but in reality without initializing the Int variable it's default value remains 0.

Comment: @MousKamel when you are instantiaitng `Phone` via `PhoneBuilder`, you already have instantiate `PhoneBuilder` and all it's instance variables are already set with default values (`int = 0` and `String = null`). So when you omit variable that are passed into `Phone` constructor, `PhoneBuilder` takes variables (which are already defined within `PhoneBuilder`) and passes them into `Phone`. There is no magic  here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with any design pattern.  Nulls are not possible for primitives, only for objects.  An `int`, not to be confused with an `Integer`, cannot be `null`.  It was never `null`.

So when you say this:

> However when I use the builder and I don't set the value of an Int variable(which will remain null)

You've made an incorrect assumption.  It wasn't `null` and won't remain `null`.

Here's a simple example:

```
public class NoNullForPrimitives{
    private static int myInt;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(myInt); //prints 0
    }
}
```

For more details, see the **Default Values** section under https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: Thank you.  You are right I did an incorrect assumption. I started thinking like that because I started on the wrong base. I was looking at a string which was null.. I got mixed up.... rookies mistake! :P

Comment: No worries, I've made much worse errors in my life ;)

Answer (score 2):

> I don't set the value of an Int variable(which will remain null)

No, it won't remain `null`; it never was `null`.  The value `null` isn't possible for a primitive type.

The `int` value gets set to `0` because that is the default value of a primitive numerical value in Java.

The [JLS, Section 4.12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5), states:

> - Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a *default value* when it is created (§15.9, §15.10.2):
>
>   - For type int, the default value is zero, that is, 0.
>   - For all reference types (§4.3), the default value is null.

If you don't want that value, then you may provide a different default value explicitly, e.g.:

```
private int ram = 1;
```

If you want to ensure that your `Builder` has called `setRam`, then you can add a `boolean` to your builder class, initialize it to `false`, then set it to `true` in `setRam`.  Then `getPhone` checks if it's `true` before building your object, throwing an exception if it's still `false`.

The `processor` variable will be `null` because that is its default value in the builder, which the `Phone` constructor copies.

Comment: It makes sens suddenly, I was mixed up because when I was debugging, before the call of the constructor I was looking at the wrong variable. The processor is a String so it's default value is a String.

Comment: Remind, instance variable primitive type default value can never be a null, only instance variable object default value can be null